# ng-repeat: sort by time portion of the date only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Imagine that you have a set of data that includes a property that's effectively a date/time stamp.  There could be any number of days, but the only part of the date that matters in this case, is the time portion of the date.

How could one use the TIME only to sort the collection in a ng-repeat expression?  Will it require some manipulation of some kind prior?

I'm currently attempting to replace the time stamp property using moment.js immediately after it's populated from the database.

```
angular.forEach($scope.timeSlots, function (timeSlot, index) {
    timeSlot.BeginTime = moment(timeSlot.BeginTime).format("hh:mm A");
    timeSlot.EndTime = moment(timeSlot.EndTime).format("hh:mm A");
});
```

When this value is used in the template, it still takes the date into account when sorting.  So, depending on what day the times were added, they may be out of order.

```
<tr ng-repeat="timeSlot in timeSlots | orderBy: 'BeginTime'">
```

I've also attempted to add a new property to the `timeSlot` object entirely, then sort by that.  Unfortunately, the date portion of the time stamp appears to be carried over still.

Angular Controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.timeSlots, function (timeSlot, index) {
    timeSlot.BeginTimeDisplay = moment(timeSlot.BeginTime).format("hh:mm A");
    timeSlot.EndTimeDisplay = moment(timeSlot.EndTime).format("hh:mm A");
});
```

Angular Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="timeSlot in timeSlots | orderBy: 'BeginTimeDisplay'">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not calculate that timestamp yourself:

```
var date = new Date;
date.setTime(timeSlot.BeginTime);

var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var hours = date.getHours();

timeSlot.ts = hours*60*60+minutes*60+seconds;
```

then 
    `<tr ng-repeat="timeSlot in timeSlots | orderBy: 'ts'">`

Comment: After a bit of conversion since the date/time is coming from .Net and a minor typo fix from your example (minute/minutes), this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: That's great. Sorry about that typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the time into a number in maybe seconds, and save in BeginTimeDisplay and EndTimeDisplay, unless you are displaying these properties, in which case, you should save them in different properties. If you do that, the orderBy angularJS clause should work easily.